# Why does MyBatis close sessions after executing every statement?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis on Spring 3. Now I'm trying to execute two following queries consequently,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS() * 
FROM media m, contract_url_${contract_id} c
WHERE m.media_id = c.media_id AND
    m.media_id = ${media_id}
LIMIT ${offset}, ${limit}

SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

so that I can retrieve the total rows of the first query without executing count(*) additionally.

However, the second one always returns 1, so I opened the log, and found out that the SqlSessionDaoSupport class opens a connection for the first query, and closes it (stupidly), and opens a new connection for the second.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure my answer will be 100% accurate since I have no experience with MyBatis but it sounds like your problem is not exactly related to this framework.

In general, if you don't specify transaction boundaries somehow, each call to spring ORM or JDBC api will execute in a connection retrieved for this call from dataSource/connectionPool.

You can either use transactions to make sure you stay with the same connection or manage connection manually. I recommend the former which is how spring db apis are meant to be used.

Comment: Correct. SqlSessionDaoSupport, through SqlSessionTemplate.SqlSessionInterceptor and SqlSessionUtils ensures that MyBatis participates in any existing Spring transactions. If there's no transaction, each DAO call starts a new one which opens and closes the connection each time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna find out how to define transaction.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
    @Resource
    public void setSqlSessionFactory(DefaultSqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
      this.sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactory;
    }

    SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    YourMapper ym = sqlSession.getMapper(YourMapper.class);

    ym.getSqlCalcFoundRows();
    Integer count = pm.getFoundRows();

    sqlSession.commit();
    sqlSession.close();
```